# MongoDB/Mongoose schema unique not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, typeorm, mongoose-schema

I want to create a city with name and some other fields, the name should be unique but I am able to create other cities with the same name.
How do I make the name unique in mongoose schema in order to obtain unique cities in the database?

**cities.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CitiesService {

  constructor(
    @InjectModel('City') private readonly cityModel: Model<City>,
  ) {}

  async createCity(createCityDto: CreateCityDto) {
      const { name } = createCityDto;
      const city = new this.cityModel({ name });
      await city.save();
      return city;
  }
}
```

**cities.controller.ts**

```
@Post()
  @ApiCreatedResponse({ description: 'Create a new city' })
  @ApiBody({ type: CreateCityDto })
  @ApiConflictResponse({ description: 'This city already exists' })
  createCity(@Body() createCityDto: CreateCityDto) {
    return this.citiesService.createCity(createCityDto);
  }
```

**city.model.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const CitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  }
});

export interface City {
  id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: `unique` field is just syntax sugar for the corresponding unique index. Please ensure you tell mongoose to create/update indexes on the db side - it's where they guarantee uniqueness. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

Comment: It's working now, thank you @AlexBlex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set autoIndex on your connection to the database. Also make sure that you data doesn't already have mess-ups. If you already have 2 names that are not unique in your database it will not follow the option.

Comment: Should set autoIndex to true or false?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, this happens when you already have multiple data with the same value you are applying uniqueness in the table. You can take the following steps to fix it

1. i. drop the database
2. ii. restart the server

And now make the server call.